# Convert json to csv with only selected keys

Tags: json, shell, export-to-csv, jq

I have a json script with the following content.

```
{
  "syncToken": "1612442658",
  "createDate": "2021-02-04-12-44-18",
  "prefixes": [
    {
      "ip_prefix": "3.5.140.0/22",
      "region": "ap-northeast-2",
      "service": "AMAZON",
      "network_border_group": "ap-northeast-2"
    },
    {
      "ip_prefix": "35.180.0.0/16",
      "region": "eu-west-3",
      "service": "AMAZON",
      "network_border_group": "eu-west-3"
    },
    {
      "ip_prefix": "52.93.178.234/32",
      "region": "us-west-1",
      "service": "AMAZON",
      "network_border_group": "us-west-1"
    }
  ]
}
```

My requirement is to convert this json to csv in the below format.

```
ip_prefix         region           service    
3.5.140.0/22      ap-northeast-2   AMAZON     
35.180.0.0/16     eu-west-3        AMAZON     
52.93.178.234/32  us-west-1        AMAZON
```

Used jq to convert the data using the below command

```
jq -r '(.prefixes[0] | keys_unsorted), (.prefixes[] | to_entries | map(.value))|@tsv' ip-ranges.json
```

But its exporting all the keys. Need help in exporting few keys out of many keys.

Comment: Please specify how the desired keys are to be specified -- explicitly (as a whitelist), or implicitly (via a blacklist)?  In the jq program, or as an argument when invoking jq, or some other way?

Comment: I want the keys to be passed as arguments along with jq command while it gets executed. Some thing like below
jq -r "desired keys" "key values" @tsv. file.json                                                                                       
In the above case I wan the key "network_border_group" to excluded while the json file converts to csv.

Comment: Finally I found a solution to the above problem. I used the below command to get rid of the key I don't want.

jq 'del(.prefixes[].network_border_group)' | jq -r '(.prefixes[0] | keys_unsorted), (.prefixes[] | to_entries | map(.value))|@tsv'
Any other solution I can make use of is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Say you had a list of fields in `$fields`. Then all you'd need is this:

```
.prefixes |                 // The array of records from which we will build our rows.
(
   $fields,                 // The header row
   (                        // The data rows
      .[] |                 //   For each input,
      [ .[ $fields[] ] ]    //   create an array of the selected values
   )
) |
@tsv
```

This will serve as the basis of all the following solutions. What will differ is how we build `$fields`.

---

Allow list:

```
[ "ip_prefix", "region", "service" ] as $fields |
.prefixes |
( $fields, ( .[] | [ .[ $fields[] ] ] ) ) | @tsv
```

Example use:

```sh
jq -r --argjson fields '[ "ip_prefix", "region", "service" ]' '
   [ "ip_prefix", "region", "service" ] as $fields |
   .prefixes |
   ( $fields, ( .[] | [ .[ $fields[] ] ] ) ) | @tsv
' data.json
```

---

Blocked item:

```
.prefixes |
( .[0] | keys_unsorted | map(select( . != "network_border_group" )) ) as $fields |
.prefixes |
( $fields, ( .[] | [ .[ $fields[] ] ] ) ) | @tsv
```

---

Block list:

```
[ "network_border_group" ] as $blocked |
.prefixes |
( .[0] | keys_unsorted - $blocked ) as $fields |
( $fields, ( .[] | [ .[ $fields[] ] ] ) ) | @tsv
```

Example use:

```sh
jq -r --argjson blocked '[ "network_border_group" ]' '
   .prefixes |
   ( .[0] | keys_unsorted - $blocked ) as $fields |
   ( $fields, ( .[] | [ .[ $fields[] ] ] ) ) | @tsv
' data.json
```

Comment: @peak, I was hoping you'd say something like that :) Fixed. So much cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

The following variations assume a "whitelist" approach is appropriate:

#### Without a header row

```
.prefixes[] | [.ip_prefix,.region,.service] | @csv
```

Or, specifying the whitelist as an argument:

```
jq -r --argjson whitelist '["ip_prefix","region","service"]' '
  .prefixes[] | [ .[$whitelist[]] ] | @csv'
```

#### With a header row:

```
["ip_prefix","region","service"] as $whitelist
| $whitelist,
  (.prefixes[] | [getpath($whitelist[]|[.])])
| @csv
```

Etc.

Note that none of the above require any special ordering of keys in the objects in the source.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it would be to use the [update operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Assignment) `|=` to delete the unwanted key-value pair.

```
jq -r '.prefixes[] |= del(.network_border_group)
       | (.prefixes[0] | keys_unsorted),
         (.prefixes[] | to_entries | map(.value))
       | @tsv'
```

Comment: `.prefixes[] |= del(.network_border_group)` can be simplified to `del(.prefixes[].network_border_group)`

Comment: And there's no reason to have `.prefixes` three times when you just use a leading `.prefixes |`

Comment: Note that this assumes consistent ordering of the keys within the objects.